# numpy concatenate error " only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy data

`x = [[1.  2.2 3.4] [3.  4.  5. ]]`

and

`y = [[2.6660993 3.6791213 3.7325573]]`

Just want to concatenate these, result should be  this.

`[[1.  2.2 3.4] [3.  4.  5. ] [2.6660993 3.6791213 3.7325573] ]`

However, `np.concatenate(x,y)` shows the error.

`only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: The second argument to `concatenate` is the `axis` which has to be an integer!

Answer (score 1):

The function concatenate receives a tuple of ndarrays:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array( [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] )
y = np.array([[7,8,9]])
z = np.concatenate((x,y))
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
np.concatenate((x, y[None,:]))
```

Note that the things to concatenate are passed as a sequence, and that they have to be identical in all dimensions except for the axis (which defaults to 0).